# subdivision subsurface modifer acting weird

Tags: subdivision-surface

when adding a subdivision subsurface modifier this happens:

Before:
[image]

after:[image]

[image]
another odd this is that it does the same in shade smooth but i heard it what only effects the lights, maybe i heard wrong

Comment: does any one know how to fix this

Comment: your geometry is split apart. try to join it. in 2.8 select all the vertexes, then execute Mesh / Clean up / Merge by distance.then play with the distance, the goal is to get a wing as one piece.

Comment: Thank you very much